# changing search url using .htaccess/functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, search, url-rewriting

I want to change the search url.
When clicked on search button (in search n filter) the url shows as

```
http://www.my-site.org/business-listing/?search_keyword&directory_subject&directory_category=18&directory_tag
```

this url is showing

> directory_category=18

however, i want it to show url and also its results by this url

```
http://www.my-site.org/business-listing/?search_keyword&directory_subject&directory_category=Associates&directory_tag
```

changing its 18 into

> directory_category=Associates

how can i make it possible using .htaccess or functions.php file in wp?

any help is appreciated.